# Alexa Skill for TV: how to allow kids to use the skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I developed a skill for Alexa that permits to switch on/off an Android TV, and to change the channel, play with the sound, etc.

It works great for everyone, but the kids cannot use it. A user said to me that her kids can switch on/off the TV, but when they ask to change the channel, Alexa says something like "you need to ask to an adult for this command".

It looks like parents can grant kids permissions on a skill, but the mum said my skill is not listed in that part of the application.

Does anyone know how to allow kids to fully use my skill?

Comment: Which category did you publish the skill in ?

And has the skill been certified or is it just in development stage ?

Comment: @allthepies : the category is "smart home" and it's certified and used by many people already (https://www.amazon.fr/Kodono-Smart-Home/dp/B08SWF66HN/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_bdcrb_top?ie=UTF8)